# Is there a programmatic way to get the "Blocking Mode" or "Do Not Disturb" settings

Tags: android, settings

I have an app that plays notification or alert sounds depending on arriving data. Using MediaPlayer to do this doesn't conform to the "Do Not Disturb" (Lollipop) or "Blocking mode" (pre-L) settings (i.e. the sounds play even if Do Not Disturb/Blocking mode is "on"). It is possible to query for many settings using a content provider with URI content://settings/ where  is one of: system, secure or global, but the Do Not Disturb/Blocking mode settings don't show up.

Does anyone know how to read the "Do Not Disturb/Blocking mode" settings?  Or does a different way of playing the sounds conform to these settings.